# A tv show where teens go into storms and end up in like a race track in a parallel dimension and fight villains for keys

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This is a cartoon/animation which aired between 2005-2010 ish.
The teens would be like put into these mazes where they would race against aliens for keys to their dimension
and I remember one of the main characters rode a yellow bike that kinda looked like a tron bike.

[image: Key]

The thing is above is a vague outline of what the keys looked like but they did have weird symbols and they used to stick to the hood of the cars when collected.

Comment: Is it anime style, western cartoon style or 3D cartoon?

Comment: yes it has a western cartoon style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Hot Wheels: Battle Force 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Wheels_Battle_Force_5)*

> One day driving out in the Salt Flats, expert driver Vert Wheeler comes across a dimension called a Battle Zone where he meets a life form called a Sentient named Sage. Together, they assemble a racing team equipped with state-of-the-art weaponized vehicles to compete against the robotic Sark and the animal-like Vandals in the Battle Zones for the devices that control the zones called Battle Keys to determine the fate of Earth.
>
> Battle Force 5 lives on the planet Earth at Vert's garage/race circuit at a town called Handler's Corners. When Tornado-like portals called Storm Shocks appear, they provide access to dimensions in the Multiverse called Battle Zones. All Battle Zones have a Battle Key that allows access to the home world of the ones who accessed the Zone through Storm Shocks. This obligates Battle Force 5 to secure the Keys before the Vandals or the Sark in prevention of the Vandals looting Earth and the Sark taking over Earth.
>
> The Battle Zones were created by the Sentients. There are two types of Sentients: Blue and Red. The two types lived on two separate Homeworlds as rivals, until the blue homeworld was taken over by the Vandals. Throughout the story, Battle Force 5 encounter situations that make them access the Vandal, Sark, and Sentient homeworlds.

### Battle Key

[image: Image of a Battle Key]

Found with a search for `cartoon teenagers storms race aliens "for keys"`, which led me to this [Better Than It Sounds](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Better_Than_It_Sounds/Western_Animation) page.

Comment: brooooooooooooooooooooooo omg thank you this has been bugging me for the longest time thank you so much

Comment: It's probably Hotwheels battle force 5. It has yellow bike, keys, villains and storms. Used to love that show.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your description, time frame .Was it "Oban Star Racers"

Comment: no but thanks for even taking the time to help me research it

Comment: and i just remembered the leader of the group(male) drove a red car similar to a formula 1 and his car had a buzz saw protruding out of the hood at the center.

Comment: There's two cartoons I'm thinking of with high speed cars with weapons
"Jayce and the Wheeled Warrior"
more likely "Motorcity"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OyAuYvijPo