# TV cartoon/anime where car racers would race around and the winner would end up in a portal as the finish line

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon

This cartoon/anime consisted of car races in a different world, where the finishing racers would end up in a portal and they would flip their cars in style, and would also receive a card for finishing first. It would look as if the race was in outer space.

Please help me remember it!  It was very similar to *Hot Wheels: AcceleRacers*, and came around the same time (2005-2008).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you describe the appearance of any of the main characters or vehicles?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the cartoon/anime you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: One of these, presumably -> [Wiki Article: Animated television series about auto racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Animated_television_series_about_auto_racing)

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Hot Wheels: Battle Force 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Wheels_Battle_Force_5)?

> Together, they assemble a racing team equipped with state-of-the-art
> weaponized vehicles to compete against the robotic Sark and the
> animal-like Vandals in the Battle Zones for the devices that control
> the zones called Battle Keys to determine the fate of Earth.
>
> Battle Force 5 lives on the planet Earth at Vert's garage/race circuit
> at a town called Handler's Corners. When Tornado-like portals called
> Storm Shocks appear, they provide access to dimensions in the
> Multiverse called Battle Zones. All Battle Zones have a Battle Key
> that allows access to the home world of the ones who accessed the Zone
> through Storm Shocks. This obligates Battle Force 5 to secure the Keys
> before the Vandals or the Sark in prevention of the Vandals looting
> Earth and the Sark taking over Earth.

Comment: And if so, a duplicate of [A tv show where teens go into storms and end up in like a race track in a parallel dimension and fight villains for keys](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231743/a-tv-show-where-teens-go-into-storms-and-end-up-in-like-a-race-track-in-a-parall)

Answer (score 0):

The one of that time period that I know is Ōban Star-Racers
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Cban_Star-Racers
They race in alien planets and is around that time that the show first aired.

Comment: Do the race tracks have portals at the finishing line, and do the racers receive a card for finishing first?

Comment: @LogicDictates - Not really, no. Sometimes they fly through tunnels and things that could be mistaken for portals; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOvb6hDMc4w